# How to call `brownie run` with extra script parameters

Tags: brownie

Im trying to run

```
brownie run ./scripts/create_myToken.py --name "Myname" --network rinkeby
```

I have `args = sys.argv[1:]` to catch --name etc like normal python

But brownie doesnt seem to like this command line format and returns error
**"Usage: brownie run [] [options]"**

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`brownie run` is designed to be run without any extra arguments besides the ones listed in `brownie run -h`.

All arguments are passed into the `docopt` function which parses the options based on the docstring. Any extra arguments that are not listed causes the parser to throw the error you are seeing.

---

You can still use brownie to deploy your contract. But you will need to perform the brownie setup and argument parsing inside your python script. Then just call `python create_myToken.py` with your arguments.

The main things to setup for brownie are connecting to a network and loading your project.

```py
import brownie
brownie.network.connect('rinkeby')
myproject = brownie.project.load('path/to/project')
```

Then you can either call your python project contracts on your `myproject` object, or you could go the next step of importing everything, similar to having an active project in the directory. Just be aware that to import, you'll need to either use the resolved name of the project or pass a name in while loading the project.

```
from brownie.project.<ResolvedNameProject> import *
# or
myproject = brownie.project.load('path/to/project', 'my_project')
from brownie.project.my_project import *
```

Comment: I found this very useful. But in this case is it possible to load the settings in brownie-config file ? I tried but no succeeded. Can you help me with how this is loaded into the project file

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139017/brownie-not-reading-account-private-key-from-cinfiguration-file

Answer (score 1):

With the [release](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/releases/tag/v1.17.0) of brownie 1.17.0, they actually introduced the possibility to pass `args` and `kwargs` into the `brownie run` cli-command using the syntax as in the example below:

`brownie run scripts/create_myToken.py yourFunctionName args kwargs --network rinkeby`

For further details see https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/398