# Brownie not reading Account Private key from cinfiguration file

Tags: solidity, python, brownie

I am using brownie to deploy the mart contract. But the brownie configuration file details is not accessing in deployment.py

**brownie-config.yaml**

```
project_structure:
    build: build
    contracts: contracts
    interfaces: interfaces
    reports: reports
    scripts: scripts
    tests: tests

dotenv: .env

wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}

networks:
    default: development
    development:
        gas_limit: max
        gas_buffer: 1
        gas_price: 70
        max_fee: null
        priority_fee: 60
        reverting_tx_gas_limit: max
        default_contract_owner: true
        cmd_settings: null
```

**.env**

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=0x<PRIVATE KEY>
```

**deployment.py**

```
from brownie import project, Contract, accounts, config
import brownie

myproject = project.load('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/my_contract_local')
account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
print(account)
```

This give me the following error

```
KeyError: 'wallets'
```

**Update**

I am executing this file using `$ python deployment.py`
and not using `$ brownie run deployment.py`

Comment: You need to use "brownie run /path/deployment.py it isn't supposed to work without it. But also note that the issue here seems to be directly related with the way you adding a new account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your private key in `'` (single quotes) in the .env file like this?

```
export PRIVATE_KEY='a714b2b7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: I tried with and without single quotes